# Tensorflow: Multiplication between 3d tensor and a matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to compute a dot product between a 3d tensor and a 2d tensor. I am not sure if this is correct way to do it. Specifically, I want to multiply a matrix [10, 512] with a vector [1, 512] but looking for a way to do it efficiently when having a 3d tensor and a matrix.

```
f = tf.placeholder(shape = [5, 10, 512], dtype = tf.float32)
g = tf.placeholder(shape = [5, 512], dtype = tf.float32)
g = tf.expand_dims(g, 1)

m = tf.reduce_sum( tf.multiply( f, g ), 2 , keep_dims = False )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrix multiplication directly, as you can represent a dot product as matrix multiplication after transposing one of the vector. So, in your case it will be something like

```
f = tf.placeholder(shape = [5, 10, 512], dtype = tf.float32)
g = tf.placeholder(shape = [5, 512], dtype = tf.float32)
new_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 2)
m = tf.matmul(f, g)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use einsum for this. The reference is:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum

You can specify exactly which element wise equation you want to multiply and it works for any number of dimensions.

```
f = tf.placeholder(shape = [5, 10, 512], dtype=tf.float32)
g = tf.placeholder(shape = [5,512], type = tf.float32)
m = tf.einsum('aij,aj->ai', f, g)
```

Here a = 5, I = 10, j = 512